# Detect and block / redirect visitor based on ISP / ASN using Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, ip

I have a rather peculiar request. I am using a static site hosting, and would like to have a way that i can detect and redirect a visitor based on their ISP or ASN using javascript.

I understand it's not practical in all scenario, but the site after the redirect won't function if the visitor has js turned off anyhow, so i don't care about js supported or not.

Using ASN should be much easier, specifically i want to redirect bots to somewhere else.

Comment: This is unlikely to be possible as the bots may just ignore the javascript.

Comment: @Simon It doesn't matter even if the bots read or ignore the js, i can also make the bot stay at the domain and never get redirected.